# How to search in between `xml` tags in `perl`?

Tags: regex, xml, perl, xml-parsing

I have two xml file looks something like this 

**file1.xml**

```
< uf>232< /uf>
< boid>32892< /boid>
< end> End of xml 1 < /end>
```

**file2.xml**

```
< id> 232 < /id>
< boid>< /boid>
< end> End of xml 2 < /end>
```

I have to write a function in perl which will copy the numbers in between `< boid>` tag of `file1.xml` and write in between `< boid>` tag of `file2.xml`.
Problem is I am not allowed to include any parsing module as its an enhancement,
I have tried something like this :

```
open(my $vt_open1 ,'<' "file1.xml");<br>
open(my $vt_open2 ,'+>' "file2.xml");<br>
select $vt_open2  or die $!;
while($vt_open1){
    if ($. == 2) {
        print $vt_open1;
    }
```

}

This is not working and is writing the entire file.
I am having trouble in finding the logic, and using line number is not a good logic,

I am new to perl, Appreciate the help.

Comment: This post, like your previous posts, is poorly formatted and difficult to understand. Indent your post by 4 spaces to show code; there's no need to use HTML in order to format your question.

Comment: Why can't you use any parsing module? "Enhancement" means "an increase or improvement in quality, value, or extent" which I find hard to interpret negatively.

Comment: I was getting some comments regarding restriction in production env , i argued but no hope :(

Comment: _Of course_ your code isn't doing what you want. No part of it does anything even close to what you've described.

Comment: If you can't use an XML library, then you'll need to use Perl's built-in text processing capabilities, and that probably means regular expressions and the [`m//` and `s///` operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Comment: Thanks @MattJacob Tried the same in Unix : grep -wF "boid" file1.xml | grep [0-9]*  
this is giving me the number in between the tags,which I can use .
now struggling to implement the same in Perl

Comment: But regular expressions are inherently a VERY BAD IDEA to parse XML. XML has context, regular expressions do not. `xpath` - is XML's equivalent of regex, and that _does_ work in a contextual way.

Comment: @Sobrique Of course it's a bad idea, but when you've got work to do and IT is impeding you at every turn, what choice do you have?

Comment: Local install. Or raise a request to install the parser you need to do that job, and get your manager to sign it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. Use a library. Seriously. [It's an utterly terrible idea to hack together your own parser just because you don't want to install one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) XML is contextual. Regex is not. It will NEVER be better than a dirty hack to parse XML with regex, and you don't need to, because `xpath` exists.

Most standard distributions include `XML::Twig` as a package, so you don't even have to CPAN it. Or you can install it 'locally':

["How do I keep my own module library/directory"](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-keep-my-own-module-library-directory)

You will *always* be creating brittle code by doing this.

However, just because I've been there and got stuck doing it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $xml1 = '
<xml>
<uf>232</uf>
<boid>32892</boid>
<end> End of xml 1 </end>
</xml>';

my ( $boid_value ) = $xml1=~ m,<boid>([^<]+)</boid>,ms;
print $boid_value;

my $xml2 = '
<xml>
<uf>232</uf>
<boid></boid>
<end> End of xml 2 </end>
</xml>';

$xml2 =~ s,<boid>[^<]*</boid>,<boid>$boid_value</boid>,ms;

print "Modified XML is:\n";
print $xml2;
```

I will caveat this with - this will always be a risky choice, and may one day break entirely, because you can reformat XML in a bunch of different ways that are semantically identical. Or someone might add an attribute to `<boid>` one day, or something similar, and your thing will just break.

For the  sake of comparison - with `XML::Twig` this looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig; 

my $xml1 = '
<xml>
<uf>232</uf>
<boid>32892</boid>
<end> End of xml 1 </end>
</xml>';

my $xml2 = '
<xml>
<uf>232</uf>
<boid></boid>
<end> End of xml 2 </end>
</xml>';

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parse ( $xml1 );
my $second_xml =  XML::Twig -> new -> parse ( $xml2 );

my $boid_value = $twig -> get_xpath('//boid',0)->text;

$_ -> set_text($boid_value) for $second_xml->get_xpath('//boid');

$second_xml -> set_pretty_print('indented');
$second_xml -> print;
```

Comment: for html (xml), I recommend: Mojo::DOM or HTML::TreeBuilder